# How to create a complex/nested js object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following data.

**var data = "a.b.c.d"; //Just an example but can be more deep.**

1. A nested structure as a string to create a.b.c.n

Now i want to create a js object from this data like this..

```
{
  "a":{
     "b":{
        "c":{
            and so on till the given depth.  
          }
       }
  }

}
```

## What i have tried

```
function createHierarchy( obj, group, i){

    if(i === group.length){
        return obj;
    }
    else{
        if(obj[group[i]] === undefined)
        {
            obj[group[i]] = new Object();

        }

        createHierarchy(obj[group[i]], group, ++i); 
    }
}
```

## Problem

This function is returning me undefined as i am sending the newly created subobject in every recursive call and since the newly created object is {} , hence the final result is undefined.

## Update

I want to create the object only if it does not exist.For eg : if d already exists ill insert a value into it.
else ill create it.

So this is what i added to @Tholle's answer.

```
if(temp[array[i]] === undefined)
            temp = temp[array[i]] = {};
        else
            temp = temp[array[i]][name] = value;
```

So kindly suggest a way out.

Comment: Did you try `JSON.parse(text);` ?

Comment: @StoyanDekov I dont think that would help, as the text that parse function needs has to be a an js object(of type string) ...Right ? And i don't have that

Comment: Can you provide an example of your nested structure, or is it simply a string such as `'a.b.c.n'`?

Comment: Try `return createHierarchy(...)`

Comment: How is the data you're getting structured? If you provide an example we might be able to give better suggestions.

Comment: @RickHitchcock  Yes its simply a string and the last n is to tell that i can be very deep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var data = "a.b.c.n";
var array = data.split(".");

var result = {};
var temp = result;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    temp = temp[array[i]] = {};
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: temp and result point to same location and hence every change in temp is reflected in result ? Is that it ?

Comment: Right on the money. And for every iteration in the loop, the temp variable references one level deeper, and the result variable is just a reference to the entire object.

Comment: One more thing , i would like to create an object only if it does not exist.

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Consider making another question, since this one is answered.

Comment: I think its just an enhancement so i did not add a new question....But i did it , ill update the post. Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

```
function BuildObj(string) {
  var obj = {};
  var params = string.split(".");
  for(var i=params.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
    last = obj;
    obj = {};
    obj[params[i]] = last;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

So,

```
buildObj("a.b.c.d");
```

Gives:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "d": {}
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = "a.b.c.n";
var array = data.split(".");

var last = {};
var temp = {};
for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  temp = {};
  temp[array[i]] = last;
  last = temp;
}

console.log(last);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qo21eh84/2/