# How to write the key(passed in as an argument to the function) in the js object dynamically?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

```
temp = temp[array[i]] = {name:value};
```

In the above snippet the name is actually a parameter to my function having a value first_name.

Here's the function.

```
function createHierarchy(obj, group, name, value){
    console.log("group = "+group+"\nname ="+name)
    var array = group.split(".");
    var temp = obj;
    var len  = array.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(temp[array[i]] === undefined)
            temp = temp[array[i]] = {name:value};
        else
            temp = temp[array[i]][name] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

## The object being dumped has the key name equal to the identifier passed not its dynamic value which was "first_name" .

What am i missing. Let me know if i should update something.

## Actual output

```
name: "cafebabe"
```

## Expected output

```
first_name : "cafebabe"
```

## FYI

Call this function like

`createHierarchy({}, 'personal_details', 'first_name', 'cafebabe')`

Comment: @FelixKing: That's not the problem here. The problem is that the OP is setting a default value incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code is incorrect, you can't use `name` as variable in a default value like that:

```
if(temp[array[i]] === undefined)
    temp = temp[array[i]] = {name:value};
else
    temp = temp[array[i]][name] = value;
```

Replace that with:

```
temp[array[i]] = temp[array[i]] || {}; // If `temp[array[i]]` doesn't exist, add it.
temp = temp[array[i]][name] = value;  // Assign the `value`.
```

---

JavaScript does not allow variables to be used as object keys, in object literals. In this example:

```
{ name: value }
```

JavaScript interpreters will *never* look for a `name` variable. It will just use `"name"` as the key.

The *only* way to use variables as object keys, is via the bracket notation:

```
myObject[name]
```

Comment: Agreed. Also, there is no need to use `temp`, it stores a reference to the exact same instance, so you can just use `obj` the whole time as well.

Comment: @JimmyBoh Using temp was because of something i did not disclose in this question for not going out of context.But here's my previous question that shows the need of temp variable.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390915/how-to-create-a-complex-nested-js-object-dynamically/31391352#31391352

Comment: @Cerbus , I want to know why the parameter's value is being instead of its identifier.Is it to do with how the js parser works ? Is there a place i can read it ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991: I added a little explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thanks i fixed it with what you said.